# eliminating duplication not working as expected

Tags: javascript, dry, function-prototypes

I'm defining a processor method that returns the lower-case version of the content to achieve this behaviour:

```
> phrase = new TranslatedPhrase("recognize", "reconocer");
> phrase.palindrome();
true
```

```
function reverse(string) {
  return Array.from(string).reverse().join("");
}

function Phrase(content) {
  this.content = content;

  this.processor = function(string) {
    return string.toLowerCase();
  }

  this.processedContent = function processedContent() {
    return this.processor(this.content);
  }

  // Returns true if the phrase is a palindrome, false otherwise.
  this.palindrome = function palindrome() {
    return this.processedContent() === reverse(this.processedContent());
  }
}

function TranslatedPhrase(content, translation) {
  this.content = content;
  this.translation = translation;

  // Returns translation processed for palindrome testing.
  this.processedContent = function processedContent() {
    return this.processor(this.translation);
  }
}
```

I also tried return this.string.toLowerCase(); but this also doesn't work.

The error I'm currently getting is this:

```
> let phrase = new TranslatedPhrase("recognize", "reconocer");
undefined
> phrase.palindrome();
Thrown:
TypeError: phrase.palindrome is not a function
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm missing are greatly appreciated, thx!

Comment: You probably wanted `TranslatedPhrase` to extend `Phrase`? In this case, you have to assign prototypes and call the parent constructor from the child (or just use classes).

Comment: maybe it would be easier to use class syntax e.g. `class TranslatedPhrase extends Phrase {...`. To me it looks like TranslatedPhrase is not linked to Phrase, so obviously palindrome doesn't exist there.

Comment: I'm following an online tutorial here: https://www.softcover.io/read/28fdb94f/learn_enough_javascript/objects_and_prototypes 

It's exercise 7.2.1, and I'm supposed to only change the Phrase function?

Comment: or more specifically the content of the processor

 this.processor = function(string) {
    return string.toLowerCase();
  }

Comment: There's a mistake in that tutorial: the listing 7.12  is missing the last line from the listing 7.10 which is crucial. You might want to notify the author.

Comment: ohh you are right! I was trying to change the arguments and calling upon the Phrase function actually worked in that it got responsive but you are so right, the last line is missing, I will let him know! Thank you! =)

Comment: It works indeed, your are the best :)